# Using the Youtube Data API to get Content Owner data

Tags: youtube-api

We have several Content Owners set up in Youtube (I'll call them A, B, C, D).  All of them are already associated with a Google account (I'll call it GA1).  We have a custom application that needs to be able to retrieve video and analytics data for the Content Owners, by using the Youtube Data API v3.  (v2 of the API is going EOL on April 20.)

The problem I'm having is that there's apparently no way to do this.  Using a Service Account (and Google's PHP library for talking to the Youtube APIs), I end up making a call that looks like this:

```
$optParams = array(
  'forContentOwner' => true,
  'onBehalfOfContentOwner' => '[A]',
  'order' => 'date',
  'maxResults' => 20,
  'type' => 'video',
);

$serviceYT->search->listSearch('snippet', $optParams);
```

This ends up throwing a 403 Forbidden exception.  (The "[A]" above is replaced with the actual Content Owner name.)  I can do many other calls successfully, such as listing channels or videos, or even other kinds of searches, but as soon as I add in the "forContentOwner" and "onBehalfOfContentOwner" parameters, I get a 403 Forbidden (with no additional information as to why it's forbidden).

In the Youtube API docs (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication), I found this line:

> The service account flow supports server-to-server interactions that do not access user information. However, the YouTube Data API does not support this flow. Since there is no way to link a Service Account to a YouTube account, attempts to authorize requests with this flow will generate a NoLinkedYouTubeAccount error.

However, when I authorize (OAuth 2.0) using the Service Account that I created in the developer console (for the account GA1, which is linked to the Content Owners), it authorizes just fine, and I never see any "NoLinkedYouTubeAccount" error.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Or is it simply impossible to access Content Owner data through a Service Account?  Is there another OAuth 2.0 flow I should be using instead?  The code that needs to call the APIs is triggered via a cron job; it is not interactive at all.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?